# Graphical proof of flat/spread-out Fourier transforms of Gaussian distribution

Tags: standard-deviation, integral-transforms, fourier-transform, density-function

The most general form of the *Gaussian* or *normal density function* is

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-m)^2}{2 \sigma^2}},$$

where *m* is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

How can we justify the statement that sharply peaked Gaussian's have flat, spread-out Fourier transforms, and vice versa by **graphically** investigating the behavior of *f* versus *F* as $\sigma$ varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-(x-m)^2/2\sigma^2}
\end{align}
then the fourier transform of $f$ is given by
\begin{align}
F(\xi) =&\  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-2\pi i x\xi}e^{-(x-m)^2/2\sigma^2}\ dx = \frac{e^{-2\pi i m \xi}}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i u\xi} e^{-\pi u^2/(2\pi\sigma^2)}\ du\\
=&\ e^{2\pi i m\xi} \int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-2\pi i w(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma \xi)} e^{-\pi w^2}\ dw= e^{2\pi im\xi}e^{-2\pi^2\sigma^2\xi^2}.
\end{align}
Hence we see that as $\sigma\rightarrow 0$ then $f(x)$ will peak at the origin whereas $F(\xi) \rightarrow e^{2\pi im\xi}$ which is ''flat".

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Compute the Fourier transform of the $f$ you've written. You'll notice that $\sigma$ appears in the FT, but in a slightly different place. How does the shape of $f$ vary with $\sigma$, and how does the shape of the FT vary with $\sigma$? (You can finesse the complex-valued nature of the FT by considering just the absolute value of the FT.) Maybe plot these for a few values of $\sigma$, observing which values give sharply peaked density/FT, and which ones cause these to spread out.